# How to create a tree (parent-child) object from Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, nested

I have an array like

```
[
  "parent1|child1|subChild1",
  "parent1|child1|subChild2",
  "parent|child2|subChild1",
  "parent1|child2|subChild2",
  "parent2|child1|subChild1",
  "parent2|child1|subChild2",
  "parent2|child2|subChild1",
.
.
.    
]
```

Wherein my first string before `|` is the parent and the second string before | is the child and the third string after the second `|` is the subchild

How can I convert this array into an object like

```
[
 {
  "id": "parent1",
  "children":[
   {
    "id": "child1",
    "children":[
     {
      "id": "subChild1"
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

Parent -> child -> subchild object

Based on Sebastian's answer I tried below using typescript

```
private genTree(row) {
        let self = this;
        if (!row) {
            return;
        }
        const [parent, ...children] = row.split('|');
        if (!children || children.length === 0) {
            return [{
                id: parent,
                children: []
            }];
        }
        return [{
            id: parent,
            children: self.genTree(children.join('|'))
        }];
    }

    private mergeDeep(children) {
        let self = this;
        const res = children.reduce((result, curr) => {
            const entry = curr;
            const existing = result.find((e) => e.id === entry.id);
            if (existing) {
                existing.children = [].concat(existing.children, entry.children);
            } else {
                result.push(entry);
            }
            return result;
        }, []);
        for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            const entry = res[i];
            if (entry.children && entry.children.length > 0) {
                entry.children = self.mergeDeep(entry.children);
            }
        };
        return res;
    }

private constructTree(statKeyNames){
    let self = this;
    const res = this.mergeDeep(statKeyNames.map(self.genTree).map(([e]) => e));
    console.log(res);
}
```

but this gives me:

> Cannot read property 'genTree' of undefined" error

Update:

As per Sebastian's comment changed `self.genTree` to `this.genTree.bind(this)` and it worked without any issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use recursion for that. Take a look here:

```js
const arr = [
  "parent1|child1|subChild1",
  "parent1|child1|subChild2",
  "parent|child2|subChild1",
  "parent1|child2|subChild2",
  "parent2|child1|subChild1",
  "parent2|child1|subChild2",
  "parent2|child2|subChild1"
];

function genTree(row) {

  const [parent, ...children] = row.split('|');

  if (!children || children.length === 0) {
    return [{
      id: parent,
      children: []
    }];
  }

  return [{
    id: parent,
    children: genTree(children.join('|'))
  }];
};

function mergeDeep(children) {

  const res = children.reduce((result, curr) => {

    const entry = curr;

    const existing = result.find((e) => e.id === entry.id);
    if (existing) {

      existing.children = [].concat(existing.children, entry.children);
    } else {
      result.push(entry);
    }

    return result;
  }, []);

  for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {

    const entry = res[i];
    if (entry.children && entry.children.length > 0) {
      entry.children = mergeDeep(entry.children);
    }
  };

  return res;
}

const res = mergeDeep(arr.map(genTree).map(([e]) => e));
console.log(JSON.stringify(res, false, 2));
```

I used two helpers here: `genTree(row)` which recursively generates a simple tree from each row, and `mergeDeep(children)` which reduces the first-level trees in the result of `arr.map(genTree).map(([e]) => e)`, and then iterates over the array and recursively does the same thing to all `children` of each *entry*.

Comment: I am trying to convert this into typescript.. but i am getting error that "Cannot read property 'genTree' of undefined"

Comment: What was your attempt? It's hard to say without any code which produces the error

Comment: Ah, you didn't define `self`, try doing simply `this.genTree`

Comment: I got error with "this" then i added "self". It was missed in the question, i added the self also in question now

Comment: How is the `constructTree(...)` method being called? Could you please also post the code which calls this method?

Comment: it will be just this.constructTree(arr) on click of a button

Comment: Change `self.genTree` to `this.genTree.bind(this)`: https://repl.it/repls/KnowledgeableCloseFrontend

Comment: What if i want to retain the key to the leaf child like "parent1|child1|subChild1" in the [
 {
  "id": "parent1",
  "children":[
   {
    "id": "child1",
    "children":[
     {
      "id": "subChild1", "key": "parent1|child1|subChild1"
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
]

Answer (score 5):

You could use a `mapper` object which maps each object to it's unique path (You could map the object with each `id`, but `id` is not unique here). Then `reduce` each partial item in the array. Set the `root` object as the *initialValue*. The accumulator will be the parent object for the current item. Return the current object in each iteration.

```js
const input = [
    "parent1|child1|subChild1",
    "parent1|child1|subChild2",
    "parent1|child2|subChild1",
    "parent1|child2|subChild2",
    "parent2|child1|subChild1",
    "parent2|child1|subChild2",
    "parent2|child2|subChild1"
  ],
  mapper = {},
  root = { children: [] }

for (const str of input) {
  let splits = str.split('|'),
      path = '';

  splits.reduce((parent, id, i) => {
    path += `${id}|`;

    if (!mapper[path]) {
      const o = { id };
      mapper[path] = o; // set the new object with unique path
      parent.children = parent.children || [];
      parent.children.push(o)
    }
    
    return mapper[path];
  }, root)
}

console.log(root.children)
```

Comment: For some reasons, this approach works better for all the scenarios and is more performant.

Comment: @AshishNandanSingh because there are no nested loops and `find()` at every level. It only depends on `mapper` object. Every partial path like `parent1|` or `parent1|child1|` or `parent2|child2|subChild1` is added and a reference to the object is kept as value. Whenever a new child to that already mapped path comes up, we just need to access it and add it as it's child. If it doesn't exist, we add the path as key. You can inspect the `mapper` object to understand how it works.